# How to send a parameter in URL request that contains a "/" in the url ?, I am getting 404 "not found"

Tags: javascript

I happen to be using an endpoint that I cannot publish for confidentiality reasons. I must go through an email url, (it is not normal but incredibly I have invalid emails in the database that may contain special characters such as `"|"` or `"/"`), to eliminate them.

An example of this endpoint is the following:

```
DELETE
https://api.iterable.com/api/users/{{email}}
```

for example:

```
email=jhondoe/01@hotmail.com
https://api.iterable.com/api/users/jhondoe/01@hotmail.com
```

this produces a `"not found"` error

from javascript I am using axios to use this endpoint:

```
let endpoint = https: //api.iterable.com/api/users/
let email=jhondoe/01@hotmail.com
let result = await axios.delete(endpoint + encodeURI(email))
```

I keep getting "not found" error, how can I fix it?

Comment: You should be using `encodeURIComponent`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: There's basically no good use case for `encodeURI`. Use `encodeURIComponent` to handle individual components of a URI (such as yours). Also: Quotes aren't optional in code examples. You want to bother to make things clear to the people you're asking for help from.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Same result with `encodeURIComponent`

Comment: @Terry  Same result with `encodeURIComponent`

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Sounds like an issue with the backend configuration.